# Generating random number between 2 variables

Tags: c, random

I'm struggling to find a way to generate a random number only between 20 and 30. I have this so far but its getting numbers below 20.

```
int num1 = 30;
int num2 = 20;
int num_random = rand()%num1;
while (num_random < num2){
    num_random = rand()%30;
}
```

Comment: There are many many many example on internet ... Have you really searched ?

Comment: How about generating a random number between 0 and 10 and then adding 20 to the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get numbers between 20 and 30 use:

```
(rand() % 10) + 20
```

General formula would be:

```
(rand() % (difference_between_upper_and_lower_limit)) + lower_limit
```

The resultant of Difference between upper and lower limit will be:

```
(0, no_of_numbers_between_upper_and_lower_limit)
```

Comment: You need to be careful using `rand()` with the `%` operator.  If `RAND_MAX` isn't evenly divisible by the number your getting the modulus of, the result of the `%` operation won't be uniformly distributed.  If the number is small and the usage not something critical, it won't matter.  Don't ever do it in hard-core cryptographic code, though.  Or anything where the result really matters.

Comment: This generates numbers between 20 and 29.  The fix to generate 30 too isn’t hard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `rand()/10 + 20`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int num1 = 30;
int num2 = 20;
int num_random;
while (1){
    num_random = rand()%num1;
    if(num_random < num2)
        break;
}
```